# Tags query for instagram

Tags: android, instagram

I'm trying to run a query for a tag - `https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{tag-name}/media/recent?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`, but get an error

```
{"pagination": {"deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead"}, "meta": {"code": 200}, "data": []}
```

Comment: Where do see an error? You get empty result and some deprecation warning.

Comment: such a result actually is a mistake, because I can not get the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Believe this is down to the sandbox changes where the data returned is only for upto 20 sandbox users rather than true public_content.

I'm trying this also and seeing the same so trying to go through review to see if that fixes things up.

Comment: Thank you, solved the problem by adding people SandBox

Answer (score 1):

Well it seems that, this end-point returns only the token owner's post on this tag only. So from now on you cannot get the public hastag feeds of all users. Sandbox or Live doesnot matter I guess.